# android application with database in the cloud(internet)

Tags: android, sqlite, cloud

we are designing an application for android which has to store the details which the end users give ,into the database in the internet or cloud, where all the admins can access the same database for checking purpose through another application specially designed for checking with that common database. is it possible?

if so what is the database i have to use for?
where i have to host my database?
since there will be more number of users querying at the same time i cant use sqlLITE, so what else i hav to use?

guide me since am a noob in web apps development.

Answer (score 0):

> guide me since am a noob in web apps development.

Ahh - cos what you need is exactly a web app.

The web app has a DB in the background, and makes a number of URLs available that your android app can call over the network. These URLs read or write data to the DB. Since anyone could call those URLs you need to pay great attention to security.

As for what to write this in, it could be anything. PHP, Python/Django or whatever. For your DB, you probably don't want to use SQLite for the scalability problems you mention - instead MySQL or Postgresql maybe. There are literally thousands of hosts that might be suitable, depending on what language you use.

Comment: "Since anyone could call those URLs you need to pay great attention to security." yes friend i got to watch out for this

Comment: am doing it in java platform....so which is a best and easy online database access hosting website i can use for???

Comment: "Since anyone could call those URLs you need to pay great attention to security." yes friend i got to watch out for this.....am doing it in java platform....so which is a best and easy online database access hosting website i can use for???

Comment: Dunno, I haven't done Java web hosting for literally years. I really think you need some detailed advice from a Java web programmer.